# How obtain a screenshot of the ChromiumEmbedded browser in Delphi XE2/Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, chromium, firemonkey

Have tried to obtain a screenshot from the ChromiumEmbedded browser for Delphi XE2/Firemonkey, but the ChromiumFMX.MakeScreenshot method only returns an empty bitmap.

Anyone have any idea how to obtain a bitmap?

Thx.

Comment: What version of `Chromium` do you have ? I can't find the `MakeScreenshot` method in the most recent one.

Comment: MakeScreenshot is part of FMX's TControl component, an ancestor of TChromiumFMX.

What the version is concerned, found this in ceflib.pas. Is this useful?

  CEF_REVISION = 607;
  COPYRIGHT_YEAR = 2012;

  CHROME_VERSION_MAJOR = 18;
  CHROME_VERSION_MINOR = 0;
  CHROME_VERSION_BUILD = 1025;
  CHROME_VERSION_PATCH = 166;

Comment: Then it's not in the [`current trunk`](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/src/ceffmx.pas). There's even nothing with keyword `Screenshot` in the whole project.

Comment: I had hoped this was taken care of by TControl, but apparently doesn't function with TChromiumFMX.

Comment: Too bad `TControl.MakeScreenshot` isn't virtual; otherwise you could override it using [Domus’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11836853/60590).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, use the following (be sure to instantiate `YourBitmap` prior to this call):

```
CefGetBitmap(ChromiumFMX.Browser, PET_VIEW, YourBitmap);
```